# How to get cell index path by cell text label in iOS on outside button clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i have an UITableView on screen with some data(text label) in cells. 
Also have an button on screen outside from UITableView.
i need to access an specific cell/cell.IndexPath of UITableView to 
change that specific cell text color by finding cell text on button click.
plz help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to select the cell:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Now if you want to change the cell depending on what the text label is:

```
if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: Hi, Able to find cell by this method but table not reflect or reload with new color. using both "[self.tableView reloadData];" or "[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];"

Comment: two things to note: 1) cell will be nil if the table has not yet been initialized and 2) when you call [self.tableView reloadData] it calls cellForRowAtIndexPath to draw the table. Make sure you're not overwriting the change you just made.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method to get the corresponding cell. see below example to change the text colour of list cell.

example:

```
   UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    UILabel *label=cell.textLabel;
    label.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: I don't want to access the cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath b'coz i need to change cell color on outside button click by passing the cell text label name then find the cellIndexPath by text label and perform specific task on cell

Comment: Do you have static cells or dynamic prototypes in the table view? Which class is the datasource for the table view? Where do you store the text information for every cell? In an NSArray? The otside button is on every cell? How does the button which cell has to change the color?